# Does multibyte character interfere with end-line character within a regex?

Tags: ruby, regex, encoding, multibyte, ruby-2.0

With this regex:

```
regex1 = /\z/
```

the following strings match:

```
"hello" =~ regex1 # => 5
"こんにちは" =~ regex1 # => 5
```

but with these regexes:

```
regex2 = /#$/?\z/
regex3 = /\n?\z/
```

they show difference:

```
"hello" =~ regex2 # => 5
"hello" =~ regex3 # => 5
"こんにちは" =~ regex2 # => nil
"こんにちは" =~ regex3 # => nil
```

What is interfering? The string encoding is UTF-8, and the OS is Linux (i.e., `$/` is `"\n"`). Are the multibyte characters interfering with `$/`? How?

Comment: FYI: `/[[:space:]]?\z/` works.

Comment: I started to feel it is a bug, and reported [here](http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/8210), but answers are still appreciated.

Comment: Interestingly enough, `"こんにちは" =~ /\n?$/` says `5`. I'm also seeing the same behavior in both cases in 2.0 and 1.9.

Comment: Not an expert in UTF-8 related things, but this is looking like a bug to me.

Comment: It doesn’t seem to be just newlines: `"こんにちは" =~ /a?\z/` => `nil`.

Comment: In [Ruby trunk](http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/8210), the issue has now been accepted as a bug. Hopefully, it will be fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [Ruby trunk](http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/8210), the issue has now been accepted as a bug. Hopefully, it will be fixed.

Update: Two patches have been posted in Ruby trunk.

Comment: Update: The bug fix will be incorporated.

Answer (score 3):

The problem you reported is definitely a bug of the `Regexp` of `RUBY_VERSION #=> "2.0.0"` but already existing in previous 1.9 when the encoding allow multi-byte chars such as `__ENCODING__ #=> #<Encoding:UTF-8>`

Does not depend on Linux , it's possibile to reproduce the same behavoir in OSX and Windows too.

In the while [bug 8210](http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/8210) will be fixed,  we can help by *isolating* and *understanding* the cases in which the problem occurs.
This can also be useful for any *workaround* when applicable to specific cases.

I understand that the problem occurs when:

- searching something before **end of string** `\z`.
- and the last character of the string is **multi-byte**.
- and the the before search uses **zero or one** pattern `?`
- but the number of **zero or one** char searched in less than the number of **bytes** of the last character.

The bug may be caused by misunderstandings between the number of bytes and the number of chars that is actually checked by the regular expression engine.

A few examples may help:

### TEST 1: where last character:"は" is 3 bytes:

```
s = "んにちは"
```

#### testing for zero or one of ん [3 bytes] before end of string:

```
s =~ /ん?\z/u   #=> 4"       # OK it works 3 == 3
```

#### when we try with  ç [2 bytes]

```
s =~ /ç?\z/u   #=> nil       # KO: BUG when 3 > 2
s =~ /x?ç?\z/u #=> 4         # OK it works 3 == ( 1+2 )
```

#### when test for zero or one of \n [1 bytes]

```
s =~ /\n?\z/u #=> nil"      # KO: BUG when 3 > 1
s =~ /\n?\n?\z/u #=> nil"   # KO: BUG when 3 > 2
s =~ /\n?\n?\n?\z/u #=> 4"  # OK it works 3 == ( 1+1+1)
```

By results of TEST1 we can assert:  *if the last multi-byte character of the string is 3 bytes , then the 'zero or one before' test only works when we test for at least 3 bytes (not 3 character) before.*

### TEST 2: Where last character **"ç"** is 2 bytes

```
s = "in French there is the ç"
```

#### check for zero or one of ん [3 bytes]"

```
s =~ /ん?\z/u #=> 24        # OK 2 <= 3
```

#### check for zero or one of é [2 bytes]

```
s =~ /é?\z/u #=> 24         # OK 2 == 2
s =~ /x?é?\z/u #=> 24       # OK 2 < (2+1)
```

#### test for zero or one of \n [1 bytes]

```
s =~ /\n?\z/u    #=> nil    # KO 2 > 1  ( the BUG occurs )
s =~ /\n?\n?\z/u #=> 24     # OK 2 == (1+1)
s =~ /\n?\n?\n?\z/u #=> 24  # OK 2 < (1+1+1)
```

By results of TEST2 we can assert: *if the last multi-byte character of the string is 2 bytes , then the 'zero or one before' test only works when we check for at least 2 bytes (not 2 character) before.*

When the multi-byte character is not at the end of the string I found it works correctly.

[public gist with my test code available here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5339185)

Comment: I cannot understand this answer at all. Also, you have `z` in the regexes instead of `\z`. What is "KO"?

Comment: I'm sorry, I was a little tired last night when I post the answer so I miss \ before \z. Thanks for letting me know. now i fixed the answer. Please  [see the code](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5339185) and play around with it. In my opinion it make sense.