# Ruby 2.0 regex and cyrillic

Tags: ruby, regex, ruby-2.0

Before ruby 2.0, regex worked this way:

```
/\A[a-zа-я\d]+\z/i          =~ 'привет' # => 0
/\A[a-z\p{Cyrillic}\d]+\z/i =~ 'привет' # => 0
```

I updated ruby 2.0, and it has a bug:

```
/\A[a-zа-я\d]+\z/i          =~ 'привет' # => nil
/\A[a-z\p{Cyrillic}\d]+\z/i =~ 'привет' # => nil
```

How can I deal with this problem? Without `\d` in the character class, it works correctly:

```
/\A[a-zа-я]+\z/i            =~ 'привет' # => 0
```

Comment: On my box (Ubuntu/Ruby2/RoR3) `regex = /\A[a-zа-я\d]+\z/i ; regex =~ 'привет'` gives `0` as expected. Do you consider to check your environment?

Comment: @mudasobwa Did you verified you're running `ruby 2.0`, I have the same results the OP has on `2.0`.

Comment: @fmendez I was running `ruby-head`. I admit there are problems in `*-preview[1,2]`, finally.

Comment: Mint 14, Ruby 2.0.0-p0, Rails 3.2.13

    `irb(main):001:0> regex = /\A[a-zа-я\d]+\z/i`
    `=> /\A[a-zа-я\d]+\z/i`
    `irb(main):002:0> regex =~ 'привет'`
    `=> nil`

Comment: So, to deal with the problem I suggest you to switch to `ruby-head`.

Comment: @mudasobwa I wouldn't recommend the OP to point to a non-released version, since it is kind of a moving target (that's the trunk branch of the ruby lang).

Comment: @Kvet The following way seems to working for me: `/\p{Cyrillic}/.match("привет")`

Comment: @fmendez I have no clue about the OP’s circumstances, especially is it a working env or a testing machine. And of course I suggested to _switch to head until the 2.0.0 is finally released_.

Comment: @mudasobwa "until the 2.0.0 is finally released" the 2.0.0 is already a released version (ruby-2.0.0-p0).

Comment: @fmendez I consider the version is released after the huge red banner “There were N Ruby vulnerability reports in the last 14 days.” constantly disappears from the http://ruby-doc.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug seems to be fixed in `ruby-head`:

```
⮀ rvm use ruby-2.0.0-preview2
Using /home/am/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-preview2
⮀ irb
2.0.0dev :001 > regex = /\A[a-zа-я\d]+\z/i ; regex =~ 'привет'
# ⇒ nil 
⮀ rvm use ruby-2.0.0-preview1
Using /home/am/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-preview1
⮀ irb
2.0.0dev :001 > regex = /\A[a-zа-я\d]+\z/i ; regex =~ 'привет'
# ⇒ nil 
⮀ rvm use ruby-head
Using /home/am/.rvm/gems/ruby-head
⮀ irb
irb(main):001:0> regex = /\A[a-zа-я\d]+\z/i ; regex =~ 'привет'
# ⇒ 0
```

Answer (score 2):

This bug looks similar and may be related to [this bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15779859) that I asked about before. I [reported it to ruby trunk](http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/8210), and it has been accepted as a bug. Hopefully, it will be fixed.